# Which is better between HTTP Proxy Server and third party tool for recording in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter for performance and load testing. For recording, the Jmeter has HTTP proxy and outside Jmeter there have some third party tools like [Badboy Software](http://www.badboy.com.au/), [Blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) etc.. Which should I choose for better?

Answer (score 0):

Every tool have some plus and some minus. So, it depends.

Based on maturity, functionalities provided and easy of use:-

1. Blazemeter
2. BadBoy
3. Postman

You may required them, if you find issue with HTTP recording else jmeter recording is sufficient.

Hope this helps.